# Unable to change size of Chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, chart.js

Unable to change size of chart.js on HTML. Have tried to set the canvas parameter along with defining a section and div tag and then explicitly assigning height and width in `<style>`. 
Have also used `{responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false}` yet no luck

Index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Chart EG</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="chart" width="50" height="50"></canvas>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){                
                $.ajax({
                         url: "http://localhost:8050/api/route1",
                         type: 'POST',
                         dataType:'json',                    
                         success: function(res) {
                            console.log(res);
                            divData='';   
                            var myLabels =[];
                            var myData =[];
                            $.each(res, function(key, value) {
                                console.log(key);
                                console.log(value);
                                myLabels.push(key);
                                myData.push(value);
                            });

                            var ctx = document.getElementById("chart");    
                            var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {                           
                                type: 'pie',                         
                                data: {
                                    labels: myLabels,
                                    datasets: [{
                                        label: 'Labels',
                                        data: myData,

                                        backgroundColor: [
                                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                                            'rgba(100, 200, 300, 0.2)',
                                            'rgba(200, 192, 72, 0.2)',
                                            'rgba(400, 92, 72, 0.2)',
                                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'
                                        ],
                                        borderColor: [
                                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                                            'rgba(175, 300, 192, 1)',
                                            'rgba(275, 92, 192, 1)',
                                            'rgba(100, 10, 200, 1)',
                                            'rgba(255,99,132,1)'
                                        ],
                                        borderWidth: 1
                                    }]
                                },
                                options: {                              
                                    responsive: true,
                                    maintainAspectRatio: false
                                }
                            });    

                            }
                        });    
                    });                           
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Updated the code with the complete HTML. Ignore this as SO is asking me to add more details (Unable to change size of chart.js on HTML. Have tried to set the canvas parameter along with defining a section and div tag and then explicitly assigning height and width in `<style>`.)

Comment: The width and height attribute of canvas in which the Chart is displayed should change the size. No need to change size using css

Comment: But it is not changing the size of the chart

Comment: I have tried both ways

Comment: For more clarity, use a JSFiddle snippet to let others see how your code is working or not working. You can hard code the values for the Chart

Answer (score 0):

HTML canvas [`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/width) and [`height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/height) attributes are element interpreted in CSS pixels but they need to be defined as integer values. Therefore you should remove '**px**' from your definitions.

```
<canvas id="chart" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
```

Comment: It changes nothing and I have already used this approach before posting it here.

Comment: @nomadev95: Please post your HTML code, it will make it easier to find a solution.

Comment: Hi, apologies for the late response. I have updated the code section with the complete HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an HTML code for two canvases of varying sizes. You just need to change the height and width attribute of the canvas tag.

I have added different colors to the two canvas for diffrentiation

```js
var canvas1 = document.getElementById("first");
var ctx1 = canvas1.getContext("2d");
ctx1.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx1.fillRect(0, 0, canvas1.width, canvas1.height);

var canvas2 = document.getElementById("second");
var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");
ctx2.fillStyle = "red";
ctx2.fillRect(0, 0, canvas2.width, canvas2.height);
```

```html
<canvas id="first" height="100"></canvas>
<canvas id="second" height="200"></canvas>
```